# Bootstrap blog fixed sidebar issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a blog site and I'm initially using the template on getbootstrap.com's examples.

Basically, I want the sidebar on the right, to be fixed, so that when you scroll through blog posts, the sidebar stays where it is, like the top navigation does.

I've tried using the affix plugin, but having issues keeping it in the same place.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 blog-sidebar" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
```

Here's a JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Sambolina/L3a7q/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, split out your sidebar from your column- in my earlier answer, I missed that:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1"> 
    <div class="blog-sidebar" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="130">
        <!---content--->
    </div>
</div>
```

When your sidebar gains the class affix, the css updates from `position:relative` to `position:fixed`, but you don't provide any CSS for the position of the sidebar once it is fixed. Now that your column isn't being affixed, you need to explicitly define the top positioning. To keep the width consistent, we'll also explicitly define it for both affixed and unaffixed states:

```
.blog-sidebar{
    width: 200px;
}

.blog-sidebar.affix{
    top: 40px;
    padding-top: 15px; /*or add it into the top value, I'm just weird*/
    width: 200px;
}
```

The only issue after that is handling how you'll deal with the column when it collapses- since it's affixed, the content will stay even after the column collapses. A good way to fix this is to add the class `hidden-xs` (and others if you change the column from sm) to hide this content, then create a new div as you want it to show up on small viewports and give it the class `visible-xs`. You can style this uniquely, which is probably a good idea since a navbar + nav + content on the smallest devices is probably too much.

For an example of all of this, see the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) which have a right affixed nav.
**(edited per author's comments below)**

Comment: I understand that I need to style the affix'ed item, but I'm unable to style the sidebar in the same way it was when the position was relative. If I just give it a right value, it won't adjust responsively and the sidebar width changes, which I'm struggling to adjust to what it was originally.

Comment: Can you drop a jsfiddle so I can try something specific? Width has to be defined too per above, and you might need a min-width depending on what you're seeing.

I don't know off the top of my head how to get it to affix differently if the column collapses for the smallest viewports, though I'm sure it is feasible; in the past I've always just set it to **hidden-xs** and made an alternate version for **visible-xs** positioned and styled differently.

Comment: Here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Sambolina/fhbtxjg3/1/ 

If I widen the result box, with the added CSS it stays the right width and transitions nicely. I don't know if it will be the same result for you on your display. So I could just do this for every viewport with media queries, but I'd much prefer a more simple solution..

Comment: I edited my response above, so check it out. Basically (a) you need to pull that sidebar div outside of the column before you affix it, and (b) you need to set a width for that div both affixed and not-affixed. The values I gave up there look pretty nice when you scroll, so try them out and tweak things.